# Trouble using "Integer" type in Prisma ORM schema for MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma, prisma2

I'm trying to create a model in Prisma, following the [tutorial](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/mongodb/creating-the-prisma-schema-typescript-mongodb), which unfortunately doesn't show how to use a wider variety of MongoDB types.

I see a lot of types in the documentation. For example, I tried using the [Integer](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/mongodb-datatypes#integer) field as follows:

prisma.schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Event {
  id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  EventId   Integer   @unique
}
```

When I try to run `npx prisma generate` I get the error:

```
$ npx prisma generate
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Error: Get DMMF: Schema parsing - Error while interacting with query-engine-node-api library
Error code: P1012
error: Type "Integer" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.
  -->  schema.prisma:15
   |
14 |   id        String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
15 |   EventId   Integer
   |

Validation Error Count: 1

Prisma CLI Version : 4.1.1
```

I get the same errors trying to use [Date](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/mongodb-datatypes#date) and [Object](https://www.prisma.io/dataguide/mongodb/mongodb-datatypes#object) types. The `String` type from the tutorialx works fine.

Am I missing a dependency? An import? I can't find any differences between my setup and the prisma mongo tutorial, aside from the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the type you should use is called [`Int`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#int). I'm getting that from [this Prisma documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#model-field-scalar-types) listing the different field types. The field types available are:

- [`String`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#string)
- [`Boolean`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#boolean)
- [`Int`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#int)
- [`BigInt`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#bigint)
- [`Float`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#float)
- [`Decimal`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#decimal)
- [`DateTime`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#datetime)
- [`Json`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#json)
- [`Bytes`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#bytes)
- [`Unsupported`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#unsupported)

Comment: Ok this is helpful. I think what threw me off is that Prisma maintains documentation listing MongoDB’s data types— which I misunderstood to mean they’re all be supported directly in Prisma. But I guess I’m supposed to pick one of their supported types instead.

Answer (score 3):

Prisma doesn't have type called `Integer`, it has a type `Int`.You can find the type examples here https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/data-model